# How to select publications appearing in a bibliography by year range (for ex: only publication between 2017 and 2020)?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, sorting

I am currently working on a CV, and I need to give a list of articles published between 2017 and 2022.

Usually to obtain my complete list of articles I use a .bib containing all publications of all type, and the following instructions where I want the list to appear:

```
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=nolabelbib2,heading=none,type=article]
\end{refsection}
```

Is it possible to do more or less the same thing to print only the articles published in a selected range of years?

Comment: yes you can define a check that tests the years with \defbibcheck.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot! Indeed \defbibcheck does the job.

More precisely, the following instructions in the preamble

```
\defbibcheck{recent}{%
\iffieldint{year}
{\ifnumless{\thefield{year}}{2017}
{\skipentry}
{}}
{\skipentry}}
```

and then

```
\printbibliography[check=recent]
```

works just fine to get all publications after 2017. It should not be difficult to adapt to get all publication between given years.